# How to animate a 'cloned', duplicate version of existing android View

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have an `ImageView` that sits in a page of a `ViewPager` and suppose I'd like to animate it to scale down + fly somewhere off-screen, while the original view is still present in pager, **untouched**.

What is the best way to create this type of animation on Android 4.0.3+ ?
I would like to use the new animation framework, not the old one.

One way I figured is to use the activity's `DecorView`: create a clone of the `ImageView` there and do an animation, but I feel like this is a bit hacky - the decor view seems more like a hidden feature and an implementation detail.

Is there a better way maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get around using a `DecorView` by setting `setClipChildren()` to false on all the parents of the `ImageView`. This allows you to animate a `View` from your layout even outside of its parent (and even `Activity`). I mostly use a helper method to do this:

```
public static void setClipView(View view, boolean clip) {
    if (view != null) {
        ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
        if(parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            viewGroup.setClipChildren(clip);
            setClipView(viewGroup, clip);
        }
    }
}
```

So just use this method on your `ImageView` like this:

```
LayoutHelper.setClipView(imageView, false);
```

To animate the `View` itself you should use the new animation API introduced with Android 3.0 (Honeycomb - API level 11).

[**This DevBytes video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA) is also somewhat related to this. It deals with custom `Activity` animations and they create a duplicate `ImageView` to animate the transition from one `Activity` to the next. That is basically the same thing what you are trying to do, just in two different `Activities`.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems my question was unclear. I want an original view to appear untouched. I.e. one view is still sitting in the pager, while it's copy is flying off-screen. Will adjust the question to mention this explicitly.

Comment: You just have to construct the same `View` again, for example if it is an `ImageView` add a second `ImageView` to the layout with the same picture, size and position and then just animate it. Their is no simpler way than that.

Comment: [**This DevBytes video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA) is somewhat related to this, it deals with custom `Activity` animations and they create a duplicate `ImageView` to animate the transition from one `Activity` to the next. That is basically the same thing what you are trying to do, just in two different `Activities`.

Comment: Ok, I thought so. But didn't know about clip bounds. So maybe you'll edit your above answer to include only essential info, like about clip bounds and your comment above (removing property-anim tutorial which is known to average developer) and I'll accept your answer! (so that we have only what's essential)

Comment: I think that this clip bounds thing eliminates the need to use decorview :)